# Finding the mean of certain values

Tags: r

I am really new to R and was wondering how to I find the mean of x that only accounts to a corresponding y = 0 (y only takes on 0 or 1) value?
x = 120, 113, 118, 108, 136, ...
y =  0 ,  0 ,  1 ,  1 ,  0

I appreciate so much for the help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: mean(x[y==0])